# Css inside-out vignette/glow effect

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a vignette effect.

```
<div id="box" class="glow"></div>

#box
{    
padding:10px;
border:solid 1px #ddd;
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}

.glow:after 
{
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 70px #CE1A1A;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 70px #CE1A1A;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 70px #CE1A1A;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    content: "";
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/

But what I am really after is a glow from the inside out.  So red in the center and white in the sides. The effect I'm trying to achieve is as if there is a red light source shining from underneath the div.

I've tried various things but just not able to the vignette effect to spread out from the center.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: If possible I would like to not modify the background property of #box as I need that to be white.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/2/

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anyway to do it without modifying #box?  That needs to be white actually.  I'll update my question

Comment: Is there is any need for #box to be white?

Comment: @Prasanth Yes, I updated my question with that constraint.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ this link may help you to generate your own style

Comment: please check my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `radial-gradient` background.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Here's a very basic example, you could tweak: http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/5/

```
background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at center center, #CE1A1A 0%, #ffffff 100%);
```

I also find this visual editor very helpful http://www.visualcsstools.com/

Comment: Wow thanks for sharing the editor.  About the jsfiddle, exactly the effect I am after, but what is the background image about? Can it not be a background color?

Comment: It's just a fallback, for browsers which don't support gradients (generated by the visual editor). Could of course be a background color, which i'd prefer, too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your after, but by playing around I got this:

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 3px 20px 10px #FFF;
background-color: #CE1A1A;
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VfxV2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this vintage effect   [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/qKXvj/)

`Just give background color to the box and you will get cool vintage effect.`

`#box{    background:#FFE4E4; }`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/7/)

**CSS Changes**

```
#box:after{
    content:"";
    background: #CE1A1A;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.glow:after {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 120px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 120px #fff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 120px #fff;
    }
```

Your `#box` is still white but I added `#box:after` to make it red.

### [Demo with Image](http://jsfiddle.net/bEFha/9/)